# C# Password recovery and SMS gateway

Tags: c#, sms-gateway

I am trying to make a program in forms that resets a password in AD and then sends a SMS to the user with the NYE code.

I have got it to work, but it uses my login and password to reset the password for the user. and as et is right now if a user get there hand,s on the program thay can make password reset,s fore fx Administrator.

the Quistion is how do i make the program so that is taks the Username and password from the computer that is logt ind to the domain so it only is Users vith password reset promisions that cane make the Password reset.

I am  dyslexic so very sory for my english

```
private readonly IADOperator _adOperator = new ADOperator(@"administrator", "Password","Domain");
```

Can you help?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: please write in proper english. i tried to fix your mistakes. but check them out if i didnt change the meaning...

Comment: What library are you using to interact with AD?

Comment: Landpy ActiveDirectory